# Cache management and Index management in magento

Tags: magento, caching

Why it is sometime necessary to do Cache management to disable and Index management to re-index in magento.I am new in magento so if you know then reply this kindly.

Comment: bharat tare problem avi gayo yar..

Answer (score 0):

In your development environment its advised to disable the cache because you tend to make the changes in the template / layout files often so to get it reflected on the frontend / website you are advised to disable the cache in your development environment. But don't do it in PRODUCTION.

And coming to Index Management, set it as "Save on Update" mode so that each time if you make some changes to your products, categories or attributes its getting re-indexed automatically and avoids the necessity to re-index it every time manually.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, "Block" data are the html blocks that the MVC generates to present to the frontend and even in the admin sometimes. Because of the caching and also session information, you need to log out of admin and back in for some changes to appear.

Depending on site volume, there might not be a penalty for turning off caching. If I'm doing a quick styling fix, I'll disable the block cache for a couple minutes.